# Search, find and delete directories, subdirectories and files in batch?

Tags: batch-file

This is my directory structure:

```
K:.
|
+---PROGETTI PREMIERE
|   +---PROGETTO 1
|   |   \---AUTOSAVE
|   |
|   +---PROGETTO 2
|   |   \---AUTOSAVE
|   |
|   +---PROGETTO 3
|   |   \---AUTOSAVE
|   |
|   +---PROGETTO …
|   |   \---AUTOSAVE
|   |
|   \---PROGETTO N
|       \---AUTOSAVE
|
```

I would like to create a batch file capable of deleting the contents of the `AUTOSAVE` directories within each branch of `PROGETTI PREMIERE`.

Since I create projects on a constant basis, I can't add a new command line every time.

Which command should I use?

Furthermore, what command line is needed to be able to search, find and delete empty diirectories contained within my `K:` drive?

Answer (score 0):

You can list subfolders with a `for /d` loop (just childs, no grandchilds) *)

```
for /d %%a in ("K:\PROGETTI PREMIERE\PROGETTO*") do ECHO del /y "%%a\AutoSave\*"
```

Remove the `ECHO` failsafe after verifying it does what you want.

For deleting empty folders, use the `rd` command (without switches it only deletes empty folders; just discard the "not empty" errormessage with `2>nul`

*) or recursive with `for /d /r`